# How to set different basepath for images in production and development in React

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx

I'm retrieving my images on production as:

`src="/dibble_back_end/images/icon.png"`

Which then is proxied through my nginx:

```
location /dibble_back_end {
    proxy_pass http://dibble_back_end:4000;
    rewrite ^/dibble_back_end(.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

The issue is that on development react server is running in ExpressJS not on ngInx. I'd want to based on environment variable be able to switch between production and development.

e.g.

Dev:

```
src="localhost:4000/images/icon.png"
```

Production:

```
src="/dibble_back_end/images/icon.png"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not providing details about your setup but if you are using [Create a React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) than you can use the [`NODE_ENV` environment variable](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables), something like:

```js
const src = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "/dibble_back_end/images/icon.png" : "localhost:4000/images/icon.png"
```

or

```js
const basePath = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "/dibble_back_end" : "localhost:4000";
const src = `${src}/images/icon.png`;
```